# How to determine data flow between different modules on IoT Edge without having deployment manifest file

Tags: azure, azure-iot-edge

Suppose I have got 5 modules installed on my IoT Edge. Is there any easy way to understand how data is flowing between these modules; i.e. data of which module is piped to which other module.

Any way to debug find this information ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Sander van de Velde** has written a nice blog post about [visualizing IotEdge routes](https://sandervandevelde.wordpress.com/2019/01/25/visualize-azure-iot-edge-device-routes-as-a-flowchart-in-asp-net-mvc/).
In that blog post he describes that the routes are part of the **desired device properties of the IoT Edge EdgeHub module**.

You can read them like this:

```
var connectionString = "HostName=[iothub].azure-devices.net;SharedAccessKeyName=iothubowner;SharedAccessKey=[key]";

var registryManager = RegistryManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);

var twin = registryManager.GetTwinAsync("LinuxArk1123", "$edgeHub").Result;

var desired = twin.Properties.Desired;

var routes = desired["routes"];

...
```